# Triangulation of a simple polygon (elementary proof?)

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Let $C$ be a simple (Jordan) polygon in the Euclidean plane. I would like to prove the existence of a triangulation of $C$.

This seems possible if we assume the Jordan curve theorem.
Can we prove it directly without using the theorem? Even better, is there an elementary proof?

Comment: You are indeed persistent in asking about the JCT. For that I finally took the time to write out my elementary proof. Please look carefully over it and ask me if any point needs clarifying! =)

Comment: @user21820 Thanks. I'll read it carefully. I guess it takes a while.

Comment: @user21820 I'm stuck with the beginning: "If C does not pass through int(XYZ) union int(XZ)". I don't understand this. What exactly do you mean by "C does not pass through"?

Comment: By "does not pass through" or "avoids" I mean "does not intersect". $C$ is a curve, which can be treated as a set of points. If none of them are in $S$, then $C$ does not intersect $S$. I use "pass through" or "avoid" because it's more natural when we view $C$ as a parametrized curve rather than just a set. Anyway we could continue under my post.

Comment: @user21820 I guessed so, but I think C cannot pas through int(XYZ) union int(XZ) because the line segment XY and YZ belong to C. Am I mistaken?

Comment: That's only two sides of the triangle. $C$ can touch the third side or enter the interior through that third side. But do please continue under my post as what we're discussing is not relevant to your question or other posts.

Comment: @user21820 Oops. Got it. I need time to digest your proof. I'll ask you if I have a question or notify you when I understand your proof.

Comment: @user21820 I have finished reading it, but I'm not sure of the validity of it. Again, I will notify you when I understand the proof completely.

Comment: @user21820 Maybe this is a dumb question. Anyway. I'm wondering about the following line. "Also Y and hence int(XYZ) is connected to the infinity by a path avoiding C'." Could you explain why this is so? If Y is in the exterior of C', the assertion for Y is clear by the induction assumption. But how do you prove that Y is in the exterior of C'?

Comment: Not a dumb question! It is in the exterior of $C'$ because it is the bottommost point of $C$, and so the straight path down will go to $\infty$ without intersecting $C'$ since the only point of $C$ that it touches is $Y$ itself which is not on $C'$. By $P(C')$, any point path-connected to $\infty$ is in the exterior of $C'$.

Comment: @user21820 Sorry, I've been sick. I can't concentrate on a math problem. I will return to your proof when I recover from my illness.

Comment: Oh sorry to hear that. Wish you a quick recovery! =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an elementary proof, but it will simultaneously prove the triangulation theorem and the Jordan curve theorem for simple (non-self-intersecting) polygons by concurrent induction.
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\tri{\triangle}$
$\def\seg#1{\,\overline{\!#1\!}\,}$
$\def\less{\smallsetminus}$

### Notation

Let "$int(\seg{AB})$" denote the interior of the segment $\seg{AB}$, that is without its endpoints.

Let "$int(C)$" to denote the interior of the simple closed curve $C$ when it exists.

Let "$ext(C)$" to denote the exterior of the simple closed curve $C$ when it exists.

### Proof

For each simple polygon $C$ let $P(C)$ be the assertion that all the following hold:

1. $C$ partitions the plane into two path-connected regions called its interior and exterior.
2. The interior and exterior of $C$ are not connected by a path not intersecting $C$.
3. Every point on $C$ is on the boundary of both the interior and exterior of $C$.
4. The exterior of $C$ is connected to $\infty$ by a path not intersecting $C$.
5. $C$ with its interior can be partitioned into triangles.

Clearly $P(C)$ is true for any triangle $C$.

Take any polygon $C$ with more than $3$ sides.

By induction we can assume that $P(C')$ for any polygon $C'$ with fewer sides than $C$.

Let $Y$ be the bottommost vertex of $C$ and $X,Z$ be its left and right adjacent vertices in $C$.

If $C$ does not pass through $int(\tri XYZ) \cup int(\seg{XZ})$:

Let $C'$ be the polygon derived from $C$ by removing the vertex $Y$.

Then $C'$ has an interior $I$ and exterior $E$ and $\seg{XZ}$ is on the boundary satisfying $P(C')$.

Also $Y$ and hence $int(\tri XYZ)$ is connected to $\infty$ by a path avoiding $C'$.

Thus $int(\tri XYZ)$ is in the exterior of $C'$.

Let $I' = I \cup int(\seg{XZ}) \cup int(\tri XYZ)$, and let $E' = E \cap ext(\tri XYZ)$.

Then $I',E',C$ are disjoint and $I' \cup E' \cup C = \rr^2$ and $I',E'$ are each path-connected.

Also $I'$ is not connected to $E'$ by a path avoiding $C$ because otherwise:

Let $F$ be such a path connecting $I'$ to $E'$ avoiding $C$.

If $F$ ever passes through $int(\tri XYZ)$:

$F$ must eventually exit $int(\tri XYZ)$ because $F$ ends in $E'$.

Let $M$ be the last point where $F$ exits $int(\tri XYZ)$ [which exists by continuity of $F$].

Then $M$ is in $int(\seg{XZ})$.

Let $F'$ be the path derived from $F$ by removing the section from its start point to $M$.

Then $F'$ connects $I$ to $E$ avoiding $C'$ because $F'$ starts across $\seg{XZ}$ from $int(\tri XYZ)$.

Similarly if $F$ ever passes through $int(\seg{XZ})$.

Therefore $I$ and $E$ are connected by a path avoiding $C'$, which gives a contradiction.

And every point on $C$ is in $( C' \less \seg{XZ} ) \cup \seg{XY} \cup \seg{YZ}$, and hence on the boundary of $I'$ and $E'$.

And $E'$ is trivially connected to $\infty$ by a path avoiding $C$.

And $C \cup I' = ( C' \cup I ) \cup \tri XYZ$ can clearly be partitioned into triangles.

If $C$ passes through $int(\tri XYZ) \cup int(\seg{XZ})$:

Let $V$ be the point on the curve $C$ that is in $int(\tri XYZ)  \cup int(\seg{XZ})$ and is furthest from $\seg{XZ}$.

Then $V$ is clearly a vertex of $C$, because it cannot be an interior point of an edge of $C$.

And $\seg{YV}$ does not intersect $C$, because such an intersection would be further from $\seg{XZ}$ than $V$.

Let $U,W$ be the left and right adjacent vertices of $V$ with respect to $\vec{YV}$.

Let $C_1,C_2$ be the polygons derived from $C$ by splitting at $\seg{YV}$ with $C_1$ passing through $X$.

Then $C_1$ has an interior $I_1$ and an exterior $E_1$ satisfying $P(C_1)$.

And $C_2$ has an interior $I_2$ and an exterior $E_2$ satisfying $P(C_2)$.

Then the path from $Y$ to $\infty$ avoiding $C_1 \less {Y}$ can be modified to connect $int(\seg{YZ})$ to $\infty$.

Thus $int(\seg{YZ})$ is in the exterior of $C_1$.

Also $int(\seg{UV})$ is connected to $Y$ by a path sufficiently close to $\seg{YV}$ on the left of $\vec{XYVW}$.

And the left side of $\vec{XYV}$ near $Y$ is in the interior of $C_1$ because the right side is connected to $\infty$.

Thus $int(\seg{UV})$ is in the interior of $C_1$.

If $C_1$ passes through $W$:

$C_2 \less \seg{YV}$ is a path avoiding $C_1$, and hence $int(\seg{UV})$ is in the exterior of $C_1$.

Thus the interior and exterior of $C_1$ are not disjoint, which gives a contradiction.

Therefore $C_1$ passes through $U$.

Let $I' = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup int(\seg{YV})$, and let $E' = E_1 \cap E_2$.

Then $I',E',C$ are disjoint and $I' \cup E' \cup C = \rr^2$ and $I',E'$ are each path-connected.

Also $I',E'$ are not path-connected because otherwise [similar to the above argument]:

Let $F$ be such a path connecting $I'$ to $E'$, which must not intersect $C$.

If $F$ passes through $int(\seg{YV})$:

Let $M$ be the last point of $F$ that is in $\seg{YV}$ [which exists by continuity of $F$].

Then $M$ is in $int(\seg{YV})$.

Let $F'$ be the path derived from $F$ by removing the section from its start point to $M$.

Then $F'$ connects $I_1 \cup I_2$ to $E_1 \cap E_2$ not intersecting $C_1 \cup C_2$.

Therefore some path avoiding $C_1$ connects $I_1$ to $E_1$ or $I_2$ to $E_2$, which gives a contradiction.

And every point on $C$ is in $C_1 \cup C_2 \less int(\seg{YV})$, and hence is on the boundary of $I'$ and $E'$.

And $E'$ is trivially connected to $\infty$ by a path avoiding $C$.

And $C \cup I' = ( C_1 \cup I_1 ) \cup ( C_1 \cup I_2 )$ can clearly be partitioned into triangles.

### Notes

There are small details that need to be filled in, but they are all easy local arguments. For example in all the places where we need to construct some path that is "near" enough to something, it can be done rigorously by first obtaining a $d > 0$ such that every vertex in $C$ is at least $d$ away from any edge that is not incident to it.

Also, the above proof can be shortened a bit by factoring, but I'm leaving it exactly as I obtained it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the proof is erroneous. The error lies in the affirmation "Then clearly YV does not intersect C." The bottommost vertex does not work, there is a simple counterexample with a pentagon.

Comment: @coudy: Thanks for reading, but I see no error in the line you pointed out. Let's step through it. We are in the case where C is a polygon, and X,Y,Z are adjacent vertices on C, and Y is (WLOG) the bottommost vertex of C, and C passes through the interior of △XYZ plus interior of segment XZ. Let V be the bottommost vertex of C that is in that region. If any edge AB of C cuts YV at some point Q, then Q≠V (since C is non-self-intersecting), so one of A,B is lower than V. By symmetry assume A is lower than V. Then AQ is in the interior of △XYZ, contradicting definition of V.

Comment: Try with the pentagon made of the following vertices, in that order: (0,0), (9,2), (3,5), (6,4), (2,9) and back to (0,0). We have Y = (0,0), V = (6,4) and YV intersects the side of the polygon going from (9,2) to (3,5).

Comment: @coudy: Thank you very much; I'm sorry to have missed that careless error. To explicitly point it out, I mentally assumed wrongly that A,B were not X,Z, and your counter-example precisely falls into that category. This can be fixed in an ad-hoc manner, but I think it is better to use the other extremal property that can also be found in Tom Collinge's answer. I unfortunately thought that the simpler (less geometric) property I chose worked. I will now fix my answer, and thanks again.

Comment: @coudy: Is my fixed answer satisfactory now?

Comment: I don't know. I spotted the mistake because it is a well-known trap. It appears in Cairns (1951), for example.

Comment: @coudy: Ok thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3):

I Found this .....

[image]

Here http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides3.pdf 
The work seems to be authored by prof. dr. M.J. van Kreveld and dr. W.G. van Toll at Universiteit Utrecht.

It's not hard to add the details

1. If there is a boundary point inside UVW (or on UW) then there nust be a vertex inside UVW (or on UW). Otherwise the side that contains the point would extend to intersect UV or VW or U or W any of which contradicts the polygon being simple.
2. Having chosen the vertex furthest from UW (any of them if there is more than one equidistant) construct a line through it parallel to UW intersecting UV at X and VW at Y. If there were a boundary point in VXY then by the same argument as (1) there would need to be a vertex. This would contradict the chosen vertex being furthest from UW. Since the inside of VXY is therefore clear of boundary points then a line from V to the chosen vertex does not cross the boundary.

Comment: Nice argument!!

Answer (score 0):

The "two ears theorem", proved by Max Dehn (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_ears_theorem#History_and_proof)), gives as part of its proof an explicit triangulation of a simple (Jordan) polygon without resorting to the Jordan curve theorem. It relies on the fact that all simple polygons have at least three convex vertices, which can be proved by casework (one- or two-convex-vertex constructions yield unbounded polygons).

Comment: The ear-clipping algorithm's correctness depends on the theorem that a triangulation exists, which you've not proven.

Comment: Triangulation always exists by the two ears theorem; proof is rather complicated and I will show you [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_ears_theorem#History_and_proof).

Comment: Look I **know** that theorem, but it uses the fact that the polygon has an interior! It also uses the fact that at least one interior angle is less than 180 degrees. Neither of them have you proven.

Comment: No assumptions are made about the polygon having an interior, only that three angles are convex. This can be shown easily by casework; if only one or two convex vertices are present the polygon is unbounded. Indeed, as cited in my reference, Dehn used it to prove the Jordan curve theorem, so he could not have made the assumption that the curve has an interior.

Comment: I don't understand why it's obvious. You need to make sure that at least one such algorithm does not use a non-trivial theorem such as the Jordan curve theorem. FYI, I have posted a question "How to determine whether a vertex of a simple polygon is convex".

Comment: It is actually not quite obvious. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I don't know what you mean by "three convex angles", because I know the 2-ear theorem and its proof and the wikipedia article's description is **wrong**! How do you define "convex" without having the notion of either "interior" or "turning number" or "winding number"? If you take the leftmost vertex you easily get an intuitively 'convex angle' which can be used to perform the ear-clipping, but it's not at all obvious that the algorithm will produce connected triangles.

Comment: Furthermore, the paper cited by the wikipedia article seems to suggest that Dehn's proof is complicated, but not enough detail is given there as it's more or less just a literature review. Clearly the one who wrote that section of the article does not know the proof at all, and neither do you.

Comment: Dehn's proof is in the paper. I don't trust Wikipedia itself; I look for the citations. The interior can be defined from ray shooting to infinity (odd = inside); I can tell that you haven't been exposed to alternative proofs, which I do recommend checking out where available. I have had enough of arguing with you and I will stop here.

Comment: By the way, I criticized the wikipedia article precisely because you cited it.

Comment: @user21820 although the cited paper only contains an outline, it looks like the details could be rigorously filled in. In particular, to use the ray-based definition of interior, one would need to restrict to rays which miss all the vertices and show that the parity is independent of the ray.

Comment: @stewbasic: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1452171/21820. I am fully aware of the details, and believe me when I say it's not easy to fill in the details. I know how to but it's not simple. Try it yourself!

Comment: @stewbasic: And note that if you use the ray-based definition of interior, you're supporting my point that proving the existence of a triangulation of a simple polygon amounts to proving the Jordan curve theorem for it...